# Can Krita and Blender be linked?

Tags: image

I have tried to look for myself but have not found the information I'm looking for.

I've seen that one can use the digital painting software [Krita](https://krita.org/) in connection with Blender.  But I do not remember how to do so.  Is this possible?

Comment: please elaborate, not sure what your asking

Comment: What exactly is it you want to achieve using Krita? As far as I can tell, Krita is a 2D paint application. The images/paintings created with it, can certainly be used as textures with Blender, as long as they're saved in a file format that Blender supports.

Comment: I'm sorry if I make a mess.

I understand and read English well. but the spell and get proper sentences is difficult.
So I try to improve myself. but it is not easy. I'm glad to see there are someone that can understand me

sorry again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find anything to do with Krita, but I do [remember](http://www.blendernation.com/2012/09/18/blender-gimp-autorefresh/) a synchronisation addon for blender that would allow painting in *[Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/)* and seeing the texture automatically update in blender.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ys1YGJk45RI) is a video of the addon, called 'External Paint Autorefresh' (Previously called 'Blender-GIMP Autorefresh'), in action and [here](https://sites.google.com/site/pointatstuffweb/external-paint-autorefresh) is the site for the addon.

The site lists the features as:

> - One-sided modes. Hit a shortcut in your image editor to make the    texture update in Blender. Hit a shortcut in Blender to make the
>     texture update in your image editor.
> - Two-sided mode. Work in your image editor while the texture updates    by itself in Blender, or switch to working in Blender while the
>     texture updates by itself in your image editor. The updates happen
>     only when you are actively tweaking the image, and at a frequency
>     that you set.

Comment: This was great.
Thank you.
Do not know which I like best. GIMP or Krita.
so good to be able to use both.

Answer (score 11):

You could set the path to Krita or any other external image procesing application in Blender's User Preferences accessible from the file menu.

[image]

From the image editor you can launch Krita with the image loaded by chosing *Edit Externally*. When returned to Blender refresh the image with *Reload Image* or <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Yes oh, Yes, that was what I remember
But I forgot how.
So thank you so much.